What is the best way to use grep to detect binary files?
I am trying to read a long list of files and filter out binary files. I know you can use file <filename> and then grep for keywords like "binary" or "executable" but I worry about overlooking some keywords using this approach. I am in favor of using grep directly with the -I option.
For example, this is maybe not the most optimal but you can do
grep -r -I -l . <directory>

and it will return the list of all non-binary i.e. "readable" files in that directory.
However, the command above can take a long time from what I have seen.
I did an experiment trying different methods of the same thing using time to time each command. Here are the results note, the directory in question contains on the order of several thousand files recursively:

time { for f in $(find <dir> -type f); do grep -I -l . $f; done; }


Result: 1m20s total, 20s user, 1m system


time { for f in $(find <dir> -type f); do grep -I -l -m 1 . $f; done; }


Result: 1m20s total, 20s user, 1m system (weirdly, the -m 1 did not help at all)


time { grep -r -I -l . <dir>; }


Result: 12s total, 1.5 user, 2 system (why does user plus system not add up to total?)


time { grep -r -I -l -m 1 . <dir>; }


Result: 10s total, 0.1 user, 1.5 system (clearly -m 1 helped this time)

I don't understand how grep works enough to explain these discrepancies.

First clearly define "binary file".

Prepend you command by LC_ALL=C:  Try: LC_ALL=C grep -arl "FOO" <dir>

@Andrew Henle All I can say for sure is a binary file is whatever the grep -I option detects and filters out. I don't know what the actual definition is. However, my use case is that I am preprocessing a list of filenames to feed into a text parsing script that needs ASCII/utf-8 or other readable encodings.

This question is similar to: How to find binary files in a directory?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

for f in $(find <dir> -type f) ... doesn't work in general.  See Bash Pitfalls #1 (for f in $(ls *.mp3)).  Shellcheck can identify this, and many other common problems with shell code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run Shellcheck on all new and modified shell code.

If you want to know the encoding as per your comment, then
file --mime-encoding FILE

and you'll get binary, us-ascii, utf-8, etc.

Agree.  Grep is the WRONG tool for the job.
